# Run classes in parallel testng

Tags: java, testng

I have multiple classes as below which needs to be run in parallel from testng (java). They are currently run in series. But, I want to run classes in parallel. Can I please know how to do that.

```
<suite name="Data validation">
    <test name="Test1 From DB">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.test.CheckTest1" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Test2 From DB">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.test.CheckTest2" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Test3 From DB">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.test.CheckTest3" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go for:

```
<suite name="Data validation" parallel="classes" thread-count="2" >
```

Nicely explained in their [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-suites).

From that point of view, the real answer is: read the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

Use,
`<suite name="My suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">`. Check [this](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running)